# Display a movie's "backdrop"

Tags: php, json, api

```
$tmdbResult = json_decode($tmdbResponse);
$backdrop_path = $tmdbResult['backdrop_path'];

$smarty->assign("backdrop_path",$backdrop_path);
```

I am using themoviedb JSON api, and I'm currently trying to do something like that simple: Display a movie's "backdrop_path". I got an API key and here is the code / response I'm using

the content is NULL when i use

```
var_dump($tmdbResult)
```

Comment: It means it isn't a object, have you tried `$tmdbResult['backdrop_path'];` ?

Comment: The error is disappear but it s not display the  backdrop_path

Comment: Well, without seeing the content of `$tmdbResult` I can't really tell you why, try and do a `print_r($tmdbResult);` and then edit your question to include the output.

Comment: it is like that content https://api.themoviedb.org/3/find/tt3316948?external_source=imdb_id&api_key=1dbf189da9bf1d29f7a5ec31519302c1

Answer (score 0):

`$tmdbResult = json_decode($tmdbResponse);`

`json_decode` returns an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

Hence, you should use the `[]` notation to access elements of the array.
You can use [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) and [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to help you see what the array contains.

Comment: It depends what the array contains and what are the keys. [Cf Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). You should use `print_r($tmdbResult)` or `var_dump($tmdbResult)` in order to see what the array contains.

Comment: yes i use that but it not display i think there is a error in the code i don't know where

Comment: the result of var_dump($tmdbResult) is NUL